# Using the word ‘had’ four times in a row is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> The man that willed me all he *had had had had* my name on his will since I was born.

My mind is broke trying to figure it out.

Comment: If that breaks your mind, then maybe don't click this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to parse with a small break:

[The man that willed me all he had had] [had had my name on his will since I was born].

"Had had" in repetition basically means "used to have" in a different tense, and here it shows up twice. The first refers to everything the man "had had", i.e., everything he used to own. The second states he "had had" a name on his will, i.e. the name had been there continuously since some time in the past.

The sentence is saying the man that willed me everything he owned had my name on his will since I was born.

The meaning is virtually unchanged by removing half the hads - "The man that willed me all he had had my name on his will since I was born." The inclusion of the extra "hads" puts he actions more firmly in the past, but don't change the overall meaning much.